# Create trigger between two tables in SQL Server that save in same time

Tags: sql-server

I have a form that contains two tables (`sales`, `tickenumber`) that are stored together.

The first table has a column that holds int value(ticket no).

I'd like a trigger the int value of the first table compare with the record number in the second table and make error if not equal

Comment: sounds like you need a foreign key contraint rather than trigger

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax for creating trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName on Table_Name
FOR INSERT
AS declare 
// ur code here
```

For more details, you should check [After Trigger, Instead of Trigger Example](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/sqlserver/OPUH170312-After-Trigger,-Instead-of-Trigger-Example.html)

Comment: no,i have two table that save in the exactly same time And both tables will be filled by the user. not the filled second table by trigger